# Vaadin session time out and UI issue

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-touchkit

I'm finding that the Vaadin UI goes grey and becomes inactive and the session expired message is not shown.
Also the session does not always timeout after 1 minute, I've set the heartbeat to a higher value than the session timeout so the session should always timeout before a heartbeat keeps it alive.

Here is the config and code I have related to session expiry.

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
 <param-value>240</param-value>
</context-param>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.VaadinExample</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

And in the VaadinExample servlet:

```
getService().setSystemMessagesProvider(
            new SystemMessagesProvider() {
            @Override 
            public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(
                SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo) {
                CustomizedSystemMessages messages =
                        new CustomizedSystemMessages();
                messages.setSessionExpiredCaption("Session Expired");
                messages.setSessionExpiredMessage("You have been inactive for over 30mins, click here to reload the application.");
                messages.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(true);
                return messages;
            }
        });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using PUSH or poll in your application? If so you have an issue! There is a known bug with respect to the same.

Comment: @Patton can you post a link to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

240
1 --> set the timeout to 60 (minutes)

Browser send 1 heartbeats every 240 sec (every 4 minutes).
Or your timeout is 1 minute...

If the server doesn't receive 1 heartbeat after 3 attempt (4 min * 3 = 12 minutes) Session will be closed..